# Android Section Cursor Adapter

Tags: android, listview, cursor, adapter, sections

I want to build a ListView which gets its data from a cursor(SQLite). But it needs to have section headers. I was using the library https://github.com/twotoasters/SectionCursorAdapter and it works all fine. But now with the new Material specs, I want to build the same listview but the sections on the left of the listview shown in the link below. Can someone help how to do this? Is there any other library or something Google provides to achieve this? Please note I need to load data from the cursor.

https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/67537/1095843/8h5VtFvLlRMOsqI/2015-08-19%20at%209.28%20AM.png

Comment: I don't think these are separate headers. I think they are icons/text in the row layout and are only made `VISIBLE` on the first row in each section (otherwise they are `INVISIBLE`). At least that's probably how I would do it.

Comment: @Karakuri Thank you. It makes sense. Do you have an idea how do I get Alphabet initials for every section?

Comment: Well, you have to scan the cursor to build the sections. I imagine you could store section titles at that time based on the cursor contents.